# How could I keep the value of an input field unchanged by switching between webpages and not using the URL

Tags: php, jquery, html

I am using two buttons to switch between pages.
Button A in page1 sends me to page2. In page2 I have another button, which is button B. This Button sends me to page1 again. I do that many times.

In page1 I have an input (textarea), that I have filled out before hitting Button A.
I would like to keep the value in that input(in page1) while going and coming between the two pages.

I could also modified my input in page1 when I come back from page2.

I don't want to use the URL. I have already been using it for other purpose.

I have also tried this, but it does not work.

This is page1.php

```
<textarea name="textarea" id="textarea">
  <?php if(isset($_POST['textarea'])) { 
         echo $_POST['textarea']; ?>
</textarea>
<a href="page2.php" id="button1"> Button A </a>
```

and here is page2.php

```
<a href="page1.php">Button B </a>
```

When I do it with SESSION it gets empty when I come back to page1.

Then I have tried it using ajax.
-> in page1.php

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['actual_val']) and strlen($_POST['actual_val'])>5) 
{
   echo $_POST['actual_val'];
}else{
   echo "nothing";
}
?>
<html>
     <textarea name="textarea" id="textarea"><?php if(isset($_POST['actual_val'])) { 
         echo $_POST['actual_val']; }//closing brace of if
?></textarea>
     <a href="page2.php" id="button1"> Button A </a>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('#button1').on('click',function(){ 
        var input_val = $('#textarea').val();
        var ajaxurl = 'page2.php';
        data = {"input_val":input_val};
        $.post(ajaxurl, data, function (response) {
            // Response div goes here.
        });
    });
});
</script>
//Until here it seems to works fine. 
</html>
```

Now in page2.php

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['input_val'])) 
{
   echo $_POST['input_val'];
}else{
   echo "nothing";
}
?>

<html>
<a href="page1.php" id="button2"> Button B </a>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('#button2').on('click',function(){ 
        var actual_val= <?php echo $_POST['input_val']; ?>;
        var ajaxurl = 'page1.php';
        data = {"actual_val":actual_val};
        $.post(ajaxurl, data, function (response) {
            // Response div goes here.
        });
    });
});
</script>
</html>
```

what would I be missing?

Comment: Why not use the session for this, or cookies?

Comment: "When I do it with SESSION it gets empty when I come back to page1." - can you show us how you tried to do it with sessions?

Comment: It will become easy if you will use form and submit buttons, is there any special requirement to use anchor tags? or your just want to implement the scenario you discussed in question?

Answer (score 0):

I am doing this by just adding a form and using basic HTML and PHP, If its okay then good otherwise please give more scenario, we will implement that also. May be it will help you. There are many ways, I am doing this by basic one.

page1.php

```html
<?php
if(isset($_POST['actual_val']) and strlen($_POST['actual_val'])>5) 
{
   echo $_POST['actual_val'];
}else{
   echo "nothing";
}
?>
<html>
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>
  <form action="page2.php" method="post">
   <textarea name="input_val" id="textarea">
   <?php if(isset($_POST['actual_val'])) { 
   echo $_POST['actual_val']; }?>
   </textarea>
   <button type="submit" href="" id="button2"> Button A </button>
  <form>
<script>

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

page2.php

```html
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['input_val'])) 
{
   echo $_POST['input_val'];
}else{
   echo "nothing";
}
?>
<html>
 <body>
  <form action="page1.php" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="actual_val" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['input_val'])) { 
   echo $_POST['input_val']; }?>">
   <button type="submit" href="" id="button2"> Button B </button>
  <form>
 </body>
</html>
```

Explanation: Here I just used hidden input filed of HTML and again when redirect to page1.php, I am sending the value back with other values.

Comment: Hello Azhar. Thank you for your proposition. I can not use a button of type submit. I habe already been using the url for other purpose. I use it to pass data between the two pages. That is why I would like to use something else. I thing ajax could work. Could you please have a look on it ?

Comment: Hi Kvin, Yes we can send data through ajax, but it will not close the current window and also not open new URL, like in your case the ajax is calling new page but the redirection taking place on anchor click so data not transferred because both are working separately. You want to close the current page and reload the new one without changing the URL? is it okay if we keep both pages content on single window and just reload the required one with the help of JavaScript?

Comment: Hi Azhar, I switch between those two websites using those buttons, and I pass other data through the URL. ```<a href="page2.php?already_used=value" id="button1"> Button A </a>```. That is the reason why I would not like to use the URL anymore. Both pages are necessary. That is why I was thinking about using one button to do 2 things: passing data through URL (already in used) and sending data to another page using ajax. page1.php aready has a form. And it will be submitted at the end of this go and come between those pages.

Comment: Hi Kvin, Sorry for so many questions, but it will the only way which help me to sort the issue. Is it okay if on click of button we add other value(value of text area) also in the existing URL of anchor tag? This will not affect your existing URL or values in URL. Because if you open page with click on anchor tag and ajax simultaneously both make different instances of next webpage.

Comment: Hi Azhar, I really appreciate your help. The URL is used each time I switch from one page to another. Another reason I don't want to use it anymore is that, the textarea data, which I would like to keep somewhere until the end of my go and come, is a litle huge. Moreover, it is not only one textarea.